# Cycle data between two components and service

Tags: angular, angular-services

I have my angular app that getting a json object from api, so for now I want to do it through a service.

So...
it has search component that doing the query to the the service, the service has the functionality to get the data.

[Example diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fYxU.png)

Then the second component need to get the data and render it on the HTML.
my problem is:

1. the second component is trying to grab the data before it exists.
   I want to make a cycle like this:

the search component call the searchService function through the service -> the view component grabing the data from the service (after the data exists of course) and rendering through its HTML template.

1. the json object is super complicated and has lot of arrays, sub-object, etc. so I have to run all over the fields and create a template for them but I got lot of errors since I can't just use the *ngFor because sometimes the field can be an object. (i mean what is the best way to render complicated nested json?)

Comment: Well, I think using ngrx is the better way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

After data is ready, call a function in the `second component`.
Then inside that component you can do the processing (**Typescript**) and bind to **HTML** as needed

Also use `*ngIf` s in template to validate data is there.

Comment: I worte a generic kind of answer cuz I'm not clear about the problem. For clarifications please ask

Comment: Yeah I know this is not the problem.. the point is the data not set yet and the second component is trying to render the data